# Minimum Weight Cycles with Floyd-Warshall Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, floyd-warshall

"Let G be a directed weighted graph with no negative cycles. Design an algorithm to find a minimum weight cycle in G that runs with a time complexity of O(|V|^3)."

The above is a question I have been working on as part of my coursework. When I first read it, I immediately thought that the Floyd-Warshall algorithm would solve this problem - mainly because F-W runs in O(|V|^3) time and it works for both positive and negative weighted graphs with no negative cycles. However, I soon remembered that F-W is designed to find the shortest path of a graph, not a minimum weight cycle.

Am I on the right track with this question? Would it be possible to modify the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find a minimum weight cycle in a graph?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track.  A minimum-weight cycle containing a vertex v consists of a minimum-weight _____ beginning at _____, followed by a[n] _____.  Fill in the blanks :)

Comment: I have no idea what the blanks above are supposed to be, but a cycle is a (nontrivial) path from a vertex to itself. You'll just have to adjust the initial settings of FW to get what you want.

Comment: @G.Bach I think hacker meant that you can contruct the minimum cycle in O(n^3) if you have solved all-pairs shortest paths first. It's much harder if we want to find a *simple* cycle without repeated nodes

Comment: @NiklasB. I think it might be enough split every vertex in two, connect them with a zero weight edge and adjust all edges in the way it's usually done for this operation. Then we run Floyd-Warshall, looking for the shortest path from v_o to v_i where v ranges over all vertices. Since I don't remember whether Floyd-Warshall may give you nonsimple paths, once we have a path we can easily strip it of all (zero weight) cycles in it in linear time.

Comment: @G.Bach: That will work for a directed graph like this one, provided you make the added edges from v_i to v_o in each case.  (But please try not to give a complete answer to a homework question...)

Comment: @NiklasB.: I don't understand your point about simple cycles -- if there are no negative-weight cycles then the shortest path between any pair of vertices will necessarily be simple (unless it involves 0-weight cycles, but in that case those can be deleted to leave a cycle-free shortest path, which FW will find).

Comment: @j_random_hacker Right, I didn't realize that having no negative cycles implies that there is a globally minimal simple cycle

Comment: @NiklasB.: Thinking about it, FW starts with only 0wc-free paths, and it builds paths only by concatenating existing paths.  If concatenating a 0wc-free path u->x with a 0wc-free path x->v produces a 0wc-containing path u->v, then this cycle contains x, and there must be a vertex y on the previously optimal path u->v that is also in that cycle.  But then u->y->v is a 0wc-free path with the same total distance as u->x->v, meaning that u->x->v would never have been chosen in the first place, because we only update the solution for (u, v) if the newly constructed path is *strictly* shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pretty close. Once you do FW loop in O(|V|^3), you have the weight of a shortest path between each pair of vertices, let's call it D(i, j). Now the solution to our main problem is as follows: Brute force for the vertex which is gonna be in a loop, say it's X. Also brute force on Y, which is gonna be the last vertex in the cycle, before X itself. The weight of this cycle is obviously D(X, Y) + W(Y, X). Then you just choose the one with the smallest value. It's obviously a correct answer, because:
(1) All these values of D(X,Y)+D(Y,X) represent the weight of some(maybe non-simple) cycle; 
(2) If the optimal cycle is some a->...->b->a, then we consider it when X=a, Y=b;

To reconstruct the answer, first you need to keep track of which X, Y gave us the optimal result. Once we have this X and Y, the only thing remaining is to find the shortest path from X to Y, which can be done in various ways.